# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.1 configuring JMS Store for IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: wso2, jms, websphere, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am currently trying to configure JMS Message Store on **WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.1** for **IBM Websphere Application Server(WAS) V8.5**. i tried following the below link **[1]** to configure the same, however the jars used in the url belong to IBM WAS 7.0.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configure+with+IBM+WebSphere+Application+Server

It seems the jars have changed from 7.0 to 8.5. I tried to match most of them based on the name.

```
com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar  
com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar  
com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar  
com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar
```

After adding the above jars to **EI_HOME/lib** directory, i see the following exception in the logs.

**JMS Store Code in WSO2 EI**

```
<messageStore name="WAS_JMS" class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:2809</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">OMS_QCF</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.connection.factory">TestOMSqueue</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.0</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.failover.message.store.name">WAS_JMS</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

**Exception Log**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-01 04:43:53,944] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore} -  Store [WAS_JMS]. Could not initialize JMS Message Store. Error:**org/omg/CORBA/ORB. Initial Context Factory:[com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]; Provider URL:[iiop://localhost:2809]; Connection Factory:[TestOMSqueue]. {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore}
java.lang.LinkageError: org/omg/CORBA/ORB**
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:391)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore.lookup(JmsStore.java:731)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore.initme(JmsStore.java:619)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore.init(JmsStore.java:270)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreAdminService.modifyMessageStore(MessageStoreAdminService.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.stub.MessageStoreAdminServiceStub.modifyMessageStore(MessageStoreAdminServiceStub.java:337)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.ui.MessageStoreAdminServiceClient.modifyMessageStore(MessageStoreAdminServiceClient.java:89)
    at org.apache.jsp.message_005fstore.ServiceCaller_jsp._jspService(ServiceCaller_jsp.java:265)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:897)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:749)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-01 04:43:54,007] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore} -  Store [WAS_JMS]. Could not create a new connection to the broker. Initial Context Factory:[com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]; Provider URL:[iiop://localhost:2809]; Connection Factory:[null]. {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-01 04:43:54,022]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore} -  Store [WAS_JMS]. Starting with a faulty connection to the broker. {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-01 04:43:54,022]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore} -  Store [WAS_JMS]. Initialization failed... {org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore}
```